# How to get the field settings in drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

Here is the scenario.

I have a taxonomy term reference field, which is referenced to a taxonomy vocabulary, for example it is associated with category vocabulary. Now I need to fetch the vid of the category vocabulary which is associated to that particular field.

or is there a way to fetch the field settings in drupal 7?

Comment: you have tid and want to get vid

Comment: nope. thats not the case.

Comment: you have node that contains a taxonomy ref. and you need to get vid

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a combination of field API and taxonomy API functions to get this info:

```
$field_name = 'field_FIELD_NAME';

// Get the field info
$info = field_info_field($field_name);

// The link to the vocab is stored as it's machine name
$vocab_machine_name = $info['settings']['allowed_values'][0]['vocabulary'];

// Load the vocab by machine name
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocab_machine_name);

// Finally, get the vid
$vid = $vocab->vid;
```

Comment: its really awesome. Clive rock!!!